# Show $R/(fg)\simeq R/(f) \oplus R/(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Let R be a principal ideal domain and let $f,g\in R$ have no irreducible elements in common. Id like to show prove the isomorphism of rings above.

I already know the following isomorphism holds: $$R/(I_1\cap I_2) \simeq R/I_1 \oplus R/I_2$$

I'm clueless on where to even begin from here.

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean? I don’t know of a direct sum of rings, so do you mean the product $\times$ or the tensor product $\otimes$?

Comment: The direct product I believe?

Comment: Your isomorphism is wrong. $\Bbb Z/ 2\Bbb Z \not\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. You need to have $I_1+I_2=R$ to make this isomorphism work. Both statements, that of $f,g$ and that of $I_1, I_2$ are immediate generalizations of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Yes I've forgotten the $I_1+I_2=R$. But I'm still not sure how to go about tackling the fg case.

Comment: Using that theorem the only things you need to check is that $(f)+(g) = R$ and $(f)\cap (g) = (fg)$. Both things immediately follow from the existence of a decomposition into primes/irreducibles and the existence of gcd and lcm.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that PIDs are factorial, ie. have a unique factorization into primes/irreducibles. By assumption the greatest common divisor of $f$ and $g$ is 1, which means that there are $r,s\in R$ with $rf+sg=1$. Now consider the homomorphism
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
R \times R &\longrightarrow &R/(fg)\\
(x,y) & \longmapsto & (xg + yf + (fg))
\end{array}$$
It is welldefined (needs to be checked) and surjective: given $z + (fg)$ we can write $z = z1 = z(rf+sg) = zrf + zsg$, so $(zs,zr)$ is a preimage. If we know that the kernel of this map is $(f)\times (g)$ then we are done by the isomorphism theorem. But $(x,y) \in \ker$  is equivalent to $xg + yf \in (fg)$ and with $f,g$ sharing no common primes this is equivalent to $x = fa \in (f)$ and $y = gb \in (g)$ for some $a,b\in R$. So indeed $\ker = (f)\times (g)$.